# Create a legend in MapBox GL/JavaScript for both points and polygons

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, legend, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I am making my first map with MapBox GL by closely following their [choropleth example](https://www.mapbox.com/help/choropleth-studio-gl-pt-2/). In my data I have a polygon and some points and I would like to have a legend for both with different shapes (a line and a point) and colors. I am stuck with the color part because polygon color is given by 'line-color' while for points is 'circle-color'. Do you know how to add this differentiation in the code below?

```
map.on('load', function() {

  // the rest of the code will go in here
  var layers = ['torpigna', 'bar'];

  layers.forEach(function(layer) {

  var color = map.getPaintProperty(layer, 'circle-color');
  var item = document.createElement('div');
  var key = document.createElement('span');
  key.className = 'legend-key';
  key.style.backgroundColor = color;

  var value = document.createElement('span');
  value.innerHTML = layer;
  item.appendChild(key);
  item.appendChild(value);
  legend.appendChild(item);
});
});
```

Thanks,
Jacopo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to query the layer's type:

```
layers.forEach(function(layerId) {

var layer = map.getLayer(layerid);
if (layer.type === 'circle') {
... layer.paint['circle-fill']
} else if (layer.type === 'fill') {
... layer.paint['line-color']
}
```

You may find this code helpful, as it does much the same as what you're trying to achieve: https://github.com/City-of-Melbourne/Data3D/blob/master/src/js/mapVis.js